# Given matrices $A$ and $B$ find $B'$ such that $AB = AB'$ yet $\|{B}'\|<\|B\|$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-norms

I'm working on a task where I have matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively. I need to find a matrix $B'$ such that $AB = AB'$ yet $\|{B}'\|<\|B\|$. This is mainly because currently $\|{B}\|$ is very large and which hurts the task I'm solving.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: this needs more information.  Can we pick $A$?  If we take $A$ to be the zero matrix, then there should be no problem.  Of course, $A$ can't be invertible, so it has some kernel, and you can just let $B$ be "bigger" than $B'$ on the kernel.  And what matrix norm did you have in mind?

Comment: @lulu thanks for the comment. I don't have control over $A$ and $B$. Those matrices are from a trained neural network model. But since $\ell_2$ norm of $B$ is too big it's causing issues with training and I want to tame it down by transforming it yet maintain the same product. So yes $A$ and $B$ are fixed and $\ell_2$ is the norm. The norm is measured as the total norm of all values (i.e as it the matrix is a long vector).

Comment: Not possible if $A$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Well, if $A$ is enormous, it can be quite hard to identify the kernel.

Comment: What norm are you using? If it is Frobenius norm or the spectral norm, then $A^+AB$ is the optimal solution whenever a solution exists. In other words, if $USV^T$ is an economic/compact singular value decomposition of $A$, then $B'=VV^TB$ is the optimal solution whenever a solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Given $A,B$, the optimization problem $$
\begin{split}
\min\; & \Vert B'\Vert^2\\
\text{s.t. }\,  & AB'=AB
\end{split}
$$ is a convex optimization problem with linear constraints and can be solved via standard techniques (whenever it has a solution).

Comment: Thank you I got this optimization coded up and testing and it works for small matrices. I couldn't get it to run for my actual large matrices as it requires 1 petabyte of memory using sequential least squares programming from scipy. And using first order gradient based optimization it didn't converge for the large scale matrix even though I tried various step sizes and optimizers.